# How to run pygame window on vnc remote desktop?

Tags: python, gui, vnc

I have a very simple pygame based script, mainly handling keyboard input and some sounds. The display is mostly useless. I would like to run the script without a display, using vnc(using TightVNC now).

I'm guessing because pygame is hardware accelerated there are issues running the display on a remote desktop, also because tight vnc creates a separate desktop sessions it seems to me. I've tried initialized the pygame display with pygame.SWSURFACE but I still get the `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1` error

Is there a way to vnc onto the py and see a pygame rendered window ?
If so, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4122/access-the-default-running-x-desktop-session-over-vnc) x11 allows access to the main display and that solves the problem